# Increase printing size of JTextPane

Tags: java, printing

I am printing a JTextPane in thermal printer. The is code is working fine but when the content of the JTextPane exceed the size of MediaSizeName.INVOICE the print gets clipped. As seen through the JavaDoc the invoice size is 5.5 inches by 8.5 inches. Is there any way to keep the width fixed to 5.5 inches and dynamic height depending on Preferred height of JTextPane.

```
private void printSlip(String body){
    JTextPane slip = new JTextPane();
    slip.setContentType("text/html");
    slip.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 3, 5));
    String slipText = "<html><center><h1 style=\"margin-bottom: 1px;\">Cafe</h1></center>";
    slipText +=body;
    slipText += "<center><p>Thanks for the visit.</p></center></html>";
    slip.setText(slipText);
    slip.setSize(slip.getWidth(),slip.getPreferredSize().height);
    try {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.INVOICE);
        attr_set.add(Sides.TWO_SIDED_SHORT_EDGE);

        slip.print(null, null, false, null, attr_set, false);


    } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Printing Receipt. "+ex);
    }
}
```